# $V$ is a vector space, $W,W',U,U'$ are subspaces of $V$ prove or disprove the following:

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A) if $U+W=U'+W'$ then $W=W' , U=U'$ or $W=U' , W'=U$ 
 
B) if $U+W=V$ then for all $Y\subset V$ :  $Y=(Y\cap U)+(Y\cap W)$

I need help of how to approach these types of questions, I have tried to bring a counter example for A but I didn't get it, but I still also don't know how to prove it or if I just failed bringing the example.

 any explanation, tips, hints are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition was correct about part A: there is a counterexample! Learning to construct counterexamples is a skill that takes practice. I'll try to explain my thought process for questions like these; I hope it helps.

This statement in particular might seem daunting because the consequent of the implication is a disjunction of two conjunctions, so it might seem hard to understand when this consequent will be false (which is what we need to understand -- a counterexample to an implication is just a situation where the antecedent is true and the consequent is false).

So, the first step should be to try to understand what the implication is "really saying". By this I mean you need to digest and internalize the content of this implication, which often involves rephrasing the statement in a more intuitive way. For me, this implication is "really saying" that "it's impossible to write a subspace as a sum of two subspaces in two different ways". This sentence is *not* meant to be a precise mathematical statement, but it is meant to be more intuitive and easy to think about. Does it make sense that this is just an imprecise rephrasing of the implication? If not, can you come up with a rephrasing that's easier for you to think about?

Once you've internalized what the statement is trying to say, we can try to produce a counterexample. A counterexample to this claim, based on my intuitive understanding, would be produced by writing a subspace of a vector space as a sum of two subspaces is two distinct ways. Can you think of an example of this happening? Once you have such an example, you can go back and check that it really is a counterexample to the precise statement you were given.

As you get more experience, this process of internalizing the content of mathematical statements and producing counterexamples will become easier and easier.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering! so I am trying to come up with a counter example for A, and I got something but I'm still unsure if its right.  so I picked $V=\mathbb{R} ^4$, and since I know spans are always a vector space, I like to work with them, so I picked the subspaces to be, $U=span{(1,1,0,0)}$, $W=span{(0,1,1,0)}$ , $W'=span{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)}$, $U'=span{(0,0,1,0)}$, I would be happy if you can approve if its a good counter example or not

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a counterexample, because $U + W \neq U' + W'$ (please figure out why!). Every time you come up with a potential counterexample, you should plug it into the statement you've been given to check whether or not it's actually a counterexample. In this case, a valid counterexample would be a choice of $U, U', W, W'$ such that antecedent ($U + W = U' + W'$) is true but the consequent ($U = U', W = W'$ or $U = W', W = U'$) is false. By understanding why this attempt failed, you'll be able to make better attempts in the future!

Comment: As a side note, using spans is a great idea here, because it's easy to describe the sum of two spans (test your knowledge: what is $\operatorname{span}(v_1, \dots, v_n) + \operatorname{span}(w_1, \dots, w_m)$?). Understanding the sums of subspaces is the whole point of this exercise, so spans are a great place to look for counterexamples.

Comment: Very nice! In case it interests you: you can go smaller than $\mathbb{R}^4$ and still use (essentially) this same argument.

Comment: I'm glad you got it, My comment got messed up from latex so I deleted it and was trying to fix it as im still new to writing like this :). about part B, I've sat down for a long time trying to bring a counter example, but I didn't quite get it, and intuitively it seems true. so I started to proof but I got stuck :(. I said  $let v\in Y$ then because $Y\subset V$ , $v\in V$,  that means $v=u+w$ such that $u\in U, w\in W$, from here I'm struggling to how to write formally that $v\in (Y\cap U)+(Y\cap W)$.

Comment: Can I write it like this? $Y\cap U = u$, $Y\cap W=w$ , then $v+w\in (Y\cap U)+(Y\cap W)$

Comment: About going smaller than $\mathbb{R}^4$, I went for $V=\mathbb{R}^2$,  $U=\{ (a,a) | a\in \mathbb{R} \} $,   $W\{ (b,b) | b\in \mathbb{R} \}$ , and $W'=\{ (a,0) \}$ , $U'=\{ (0,b)\} $

Comment: This example doesn't quite work because $U + W \neq U' + W'$ (why?) -- there is a counterexample with $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ though!

Comment: Actually, B is false. Hint: you can use your counterexample from part A to make a counterexample for part B!

Comment: ahh, I'm really glad I got stuck in this question and asked here to see my weakness in sum of vector spaces, about my example $V=\mathbb{R}^2 $, if I change $W=\{ (b,c) \}$, then they will be equal to all $\mathbb{R}^2$. it was false because the sum $U+W= \{ (a+b,a+b) \}$ , which doesnt cover all $\mathbb{R}^2$. did I get it right this time? :)

Comment: !!! I think it clicked in my head now about part B, $W= \{ (a,0,0,d) \} $, $U=\{ (0,b,c,0) \}$, if I pick $Y= \{ (a,b,0,0) \}$, the intersection with each of $W,U$ will be only $\{ (0,0,0,0) \}$, what I thought about is just drawing circles, the sum $U+W$ is a big circle and in it we have two smaller circles that don't cover all of it which are $U$ and $W$, so if I pick vectors outside of these little circles, I will get zeroes because they don't intersect with $U,W$. is this a valid way to think about it?

Comment: This works! Your venn-diagram picture is pretty good, but of course just an abstraction -- vector spaces don't really look like circles. However, we can actually visualize vector spaces of dimension $\leq 3$! So you should try to find a counterexample for B in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \leq 3$, and visualize exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thank you so much, honestly. you didn't only just give me an answer, you made me be able to reach and create my own answer and understand this in a much better way. I appreciate all the help and your way of giving hints is really just amazing.

Comment: Thanks very much for the kind words :)